# Retrieve _id after insert in a Meteor.method call

Tags: meteor

I need to retrieve the _id after insert a document.

In client:

```
Meteor.call('saveDocument', value1, value2);
```

In server

```
saveDocument: function (value1, value2) {
    MyCollection.insert({ 'value1': value1, 'value2': value2});
}
```

I have tried with the callback function of the insert in the server side. This way I can get the document's _id, but inside the callback function and this can't return to the client call:

```
saveDocument: function (value1, value2) {
    MyCollection.insert({ 'value1': value1, 'valu2': value2}, 
        function(err, docsInserted){ console.log(docsInserted) }); 
        //Works, but docsInserted can't return to the client.
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

your client call should use the async style - from the docs

> On the client, if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a stub, call will return undefined, and you will have no way to get the return value of the method.

```
Meteor.call('saveDocument', value1, value2, function(error, result){
  var theIdYouWant = result;
});
```

then you just return the id from the method

```
saveDocument: function (value1, value2) {
  return MyCollection.insert({ 'value1': value1, 'valu2': value2}); 
}
```

for good measure give a once over to these 2 sections of the docs

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call

http://docs.meteor.com/#insert

Comment: I had to write it like that for it to work : `saveDocument: function (value1, value2) {
  var newDoc =  MyCollection.insert({ 'value1': value1, 'valu2': value2}); return newDoc;
}`

Answer (score 0):

found this question when I had the same issue, got this solution
use .insert() on the client side and it works fine with the callback. Something like this:

```
Collection.insert({
    something: something    //insert to Mongo
}, (error, response) => {
    console.log(error, result   //get the response
)});
```