# Meteor collection.insert callback to return new id

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to get the id of a newly inserted docuement in the callback of meteor.collection.insert.

I insert the Doc as follows:

```
Meteor.call('createDoc', {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
})
```

The createDoc function looks like that:

```
Meteor.methods createDoc: (options) ->
    incidents.insert
        key1: options.value1
        key2: options.value2
        , callback(error, result)

callback = (error,result) ->
    console.log result
```

The Documentation says:

```
callback Function
Optional. If present, called with an error object as the first argument and,
if no error,the _id as the second.
```

So I expect result to return the new id, but am getting a Reference Error saying that error and result are not defined. What am I getting wrong here? Any help is much apprecated.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Retrieve \_id after insert in a Meteor.method call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439055/retrieve-id-after-insert-in-a-meteor-method-call)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

BenjaminRH is right about the easier, more likely way to do this.  However, there are times when you need the server to do the work, and/or some who insist that is the only way to do database work even in meteor, and here's how your code would do that:

```
# server code
Meteor.methods createDoc: (options) ->
  created = incidents.insert
    key1: options.value1
    key2: options.value2
  created

# on client code

Meteor.call 'createDoc', info, (err, data) ->
  if err
    console.log JSON.stringify err,null,2
    # DO SOMETHING BETTER!!
  else
    Session.set('added doc', data )  
    # and something reactive in waiting for session to have 'added doc'
```

Comment: What?  I fixed his code up to actually use callbacks correctly in the way you would need to do, and get a downvote?

Comment: sorry for that, It was not me who did downvote your answer, I just happened to see it right now and adjusted it. Thanks for your contribution, much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks!  Which way did you go?

Answer (score 4):

You mostly have the right idea, but you're confusing a couple of things. Currently, your Meteor method isn't returning anything, because you're calling the insert asynchronously by providing a callback. Asynchronous method returns can be done, but it's a lot more complicated than you need for something this simple (checkout this [excellent async guide](https://gist.github.com/possibilities/3443021) for more info).

Instead of having  a callback, you can use the insert method without a callback and assign that to a variable, like `var incidentId = Incidents.insert({ ... });` -- return that.

Then, in the client-side callback for the `Meteor.call`, the result should be the _id.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right that's definitely easier that way. The Meteor async Guide is a meaningful resource as well. Much appreciated.

Comment: If the `insert` is on the server it's performance wise recommended to use a callback. The documentation states: "On the server, if you don't provide a callback, then insert blocks until the database acknowledges the write, or throws an exception if something went wrong. If you do provide a callback, insert still returns the ID immediately. Once the insert completes (or fails), the callback is called with error and result arguments. In an error case, result is undefined. If the insert is successful, error is undefined and result is the new document ID."

Answer (score 0):

From client side, your callback function result will return last inserted object id if you return from Meteor.methods.

```
Meteor.call('addURL', url, function (error, result) {
    urlId = result;
});

Meteor.methods({
    addURL : function(url) {
        return URL.insert(url);
    }
});
```

urlId has the id of last inserted object.