# Meteor JS Iron Router subscribe to data

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor 0.8 and iron-router.

I have a single route that I use to subscribe to a number of collections. What I would like to do is create a document when you arrive on the route and then subscribe to it so I can access it.

This is my route:

```
    this.route('product_collection', {
    path: '/collection/:collection',
    template: 'product_collection',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout-new',
    waitOn: function() { return [ Meteor.subscribe('specific_product_collection', this.params.collection), Meteor.subscribe('product_types')] },
    data: function () { return ProductCollections.findOne({ url: this.params.collection }) },
    onBeforeAction: function(pause){
        //Prevent double rendering
        if (this.ready()) {


            var productType = ProductTypes.findOne({url: this.params.collection })
            console.log(productType)
            if(productType){
                var product = {
                    productType: productType._id
                };
                Session.set("productTypeId", productType._id);

                Products.insert(product, function(error, id) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.error(error);
                        set_notification('Oops, something went wrong.', 'Please try again later.');
                    } else {

                        Session.set("productId", id);
                        Session.set("productName", productType.name );
                        //Not working
                        Meteor.subscribe('specific-product', id);
                        console.log('should be subscribed') 

                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            console.log('loading')
            this.render('loading');
            pause();
         }
    },
});
```

Comment: waitOn is where you want to subscribe a collection. onBeforeAction runs after data and waitOn and don't wait subscriptions finishes before render.

Comment: Yes, the only issue is I want to create a document and then subscribe to it inside waitOn.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I found out the ID was different on the server vs client side location. So ended up writing a meteor method call on the server.

See reference: [Retrieve _id after insert in a Meteor.method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439055/retrieve-id-after-insert-in-a-meteor-method-call)